# Click event via QMouseEvent doesn't trigger with Qt virtual keyboard

Tags: c++, qt, qt6

I want to emulate a mouse click on the Qt virtual keyboard key. I have a QML application on Qt6 with a virtual keyboard.

I found the following code on the qtwebdriver GitHub repository:

```
void Quick2ViewCmdExecutor::ClickElement(const ElementId& element, Error** error) {
    QQuickWindow* view = getView(view_id_, error);
    if (NULL == view)
        return;

    QQuickItem* pItem = getElement(element, error);
    if (NULL == pItem)
        return;

    if (!pItem->isVisible()) {
        *error = new Error(kElementNotVisible);
        return;
    }

    session_->logger().Log(kFineLogLevel, "Click on:");
    session_->logger().Log(kFineLogLevel, pItem->objectName().toStdString());

    QPointF scenePoint = pItem->mapToScene(QPointF(pItem->width()/2.0,pItem->height()/2.0));

    QRectF sceneRect(QPointF(0,0), view->size());
    if (!sceneRect.contains(scenePoint)) {
        *error = new Error(kMoveTargetOutOfBounds);
        return;
    }

    QMouseEvent *pressEvent = new QMouseEvent(QEvent::MouseButtonPress,
                             scenePoint,
                             Qt::LeftButton,
                             Qt::LeftButton,
                             Qt::NoModifier);

    QMouseEvent *releaseEvent = new QMouseEvent(QEvent::MouseButtonRelease,
                             scenePoint,
                             Qt::LeftButton,
                             Qt::LeftButton,
                             Qt::NoModifier);

    QGuiApplication::postEvent(view, pressEvent);
    QGuiApplication::postEvent(view, releaseEvent);
    QGuiApplication::processEvents();
}
```

It appears that the press event works correctly and the key is pressed, but the release signal is not emitted. This code works well with other quick elements except for the Keyboard. The issue might be related to the usage of MultiPointTouchArea in Keyboard.qml.

Comment: Which release signal do you expect and how do you try to receive it? Do you use your own `QVirtualKeyboardAbstractInputMethod`-derived input method? As far as I understand, input method receives key event from input engine only when pressed virtual key *releases*, and this event is interprered as key click typically used to update currently focused text editor element via methods of associated input context. I.e. there's no separate release event/signal on the level of input method.

Comment: I expected release signal which is emitted in QuickMultiPointTouchArea::updateTouchData

I solved this problem. I added these lines before releaseEvent creation.

QGuiApplication::postEvent(view, pressEvent);
QGuiApplication::processEvents();

Also, I added QGuiApplication::mouseButtons() as the 4th parameter of QMouseEvent ctor for release event

And now it works correctly